# Replacing google.appengine.api import modules when upgrading to GAE3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We're moving from GAE 2 (standard) to 3.
On GAE2 we used:

```
from google.appengine.api import modules

CountryClient.COUNTRY_REALTIME_HOST = modules.get_hostname('api-country')
```

How can I do it on GAE3, considering that `google.appengine.api` not is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to the [`google.appengine.api.modules`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.modules.modules) libraries in the Python 3 runtime for App Engine Standard.

However, as a workaround, you can use a combination of the App Engine [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/client-libraries) and the [default runtime environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables).

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#modules):

> The Modules API is not supported on Python 3. You can use a
>   combination of environment variables and the App Engine Admin API to
>   obtain information about and modify your application's running
>   services:

As you are calling the `modules.get_hostname` with a module name (or service name, as now modules are usually referred as services), you could use the [apps.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services/get) API call to retrieve which is the version handling all of the traffic, and then the [apps.services.versions.instances.list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list) API call to retrieve which is the instance name handling all of the traffic. Then you could build the Hosname as such:

```
<Instance-ID>.<version.ID>.<service-ID>.<App-ID>.appspot.com
```

(Or if you are using a custom domain, you can replace the `appspot.com` domain with it.)